# little-o and 3 functions

Tags: limits, asymptotics

If we have 3 function $f$, $g$ and $h$ such that :

- $f$ is not $o(g)$
- $f$ is $o(h)$

Can we conclude that $g$ is $o(h)$ ?

i.e is the following true ?

$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \neq 0$

and

$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{h(x)} = 0  $

implies

$lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = 0  $

Thanks

Comment: If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists (and $\ne 0$) then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Ok thanks, if you want to put the answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not true.

If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and is not equal to $0$, then it is true. Otherwise, it is not.